# Limiting Search Results to a View in Document Library

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, search-scope

Working in SharePoint 2013 I have created a custom search. I created the Results Source and then tried connecting it to the search navigation web part because I want to add the view title to the navigation web part search criteria (the links that appear under the search bar).  But when I create Results Source based on the path of the view it does not bring up the results of all the documents in the view but just the link to the view.  Is there a way to create search criteria limiting search results to a view only?  By the way I have 4 views that I want the user to be able to search individually rather than having to enter the correct search criteria in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use view url as path because views are not folders.
To achieve this I suggest the following:

1- Create a result source for each view and reproduce the view's filter in the result source query.
Inconvenient : when you update the view's filter, you have to update the result source query too.
You have to create a managed property for each column involved in the search query

2- Create a calculated field that returns a unique value based on the view's filter. And then use this column to create your views and result sources
You have to create a managed property for calculated column to use it in the search query

Regards